# How do I do column contains with API

Tags: socrata, soda

With the GUI I can do a filter on a column for contains. The API does not seem to allow that. Is there anyway to do this with the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're looking for is the [`like`](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/like.html) SoQL function, which is available on [Text](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/text.html). You'll need to make sure you're using the latest version of your dataset's API, and you can find [instructions on how to locate that](http://dev.socrata.com/changelog/2015/04/27/new-higher-performance-apis.html) in the developer portal's changelog.

For example:

```
https://open.whitehouse.gov/resource/9j92-xfdk.json?$where=position_title like '%25ASSISTANT%25'
```